# Saving a friend's Facebook picture to disk from the server does not work

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

### TL;DR

- Viewing images from a friend's profile image album works on web page with FB JavaScript API
- Page passes URL to server, but server cannot download the image from the URL (HTTP STATUS 0)
- User is definitely logged in to both JS api and PHP-SDK API and has FB photo permissions
- Current profile images work great
- This issue does not affect all users, only some.

## My Facebook Photos App

My app creates a video montage of your friend's Facebook Images.

The app asks for the permissions:

- "user_photos"
- and "friends_photos".

The user chooses the pictures to add to the montage with Javascript in the browser. Then I pass the URL of the chosen image to the server, which downloads the image from the URL and stores it on Amazon S3.

Everything works on the client and **always works for friends profile images**. But for other images i.e. ones from an album or previous profile pics, my server cannot download the image at all.

Using cURL, the status code returned is 0. For other images, the code is 200.

How can I get the access to these images? Does the server need to pass some other data to be able to access CDN images?

The image URLs passed from my JS are long links and look like this: http://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/s720x720/408158_894440624792_192203432_41161655_469457024_n.jpg
(This is not a real image link though)

I can open the images in my browser fine, but cannot open them server-side.

I am using PHP-SDK, so the server is authenticated with Facebook for the logged in user. I know this is correct as I have tried multiple accounts and checked the current logged in user id.

To download, I have tried cURL, file_get_contents and a couple of other methods. All receive nothing, therefore I don't think Facebook is giving my server access to the picture.

Strangely, this issue seems to only affect some users, not everyone.

Also - my server is PHP 5.2 and is running on IIS.

Any help would be fantastic!

*Further info:
I tried visiting the URL when logged in with another user account, someone not a friend of the owner of the photo and they could also see the image in the browser. Odd that my server cannot.*

Comment: I neither can open this one (long) in browser!

Comment: The image is not a valid URL. I just gave an example to show the format of the urls I am seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this issue only occurs for a subset of Facebook users, I have a feeling that there may be a bug somewhere in the way image permissions are granted.

This then means there is a slight discrepancy between the JS API and the PHP API, only for some images and only for some users.

However, I have now adjusted my code to get the images another way and so no longer have this issue.